# convert JSON into CSV and merge object using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have JSON file and need to convert in CSV.
Sample JSON data:

```json
{
    "books":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "story":{
                "title":"Lonely lion",
                "writers":[
                    {
                        "lastName":"John",
                        "firstName":"Louis"
                    },
                    {
                        "lastName":"Nick",
                        "firstName":"Fed"
                    }
                ],
                "slot":[
                    {
                        "slotid":1112,
                        "region":{
                            "US":11,
                            "CA":1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "description":[
                {
                    "release":false,
                    "author":[
                        {
                            "name":"John",
                            "main":1
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"Jeroge",
                            "main":0
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"Peter",
                            "main":0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "story":{
                "title":"Lonely lion",
                "writers":[
                    {
                        "lastName":"John",
                        "firstName":"Louis"
                    },
                    {
                        "lastName":"Nick",
                        "firstName":"Fed"
                    }
                ],
                "slot":[
                    {
                        "slotid":1112,
                        "region":{
                            "US":11
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "description":[
                {
                    "release":false,
                    "author":[
                        {
                            "name":"Jeroge",
                            "main":1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I used the below code:

```
with open(jsonFilename, 'r',encoding='UTF-8') as jsonInput:
    json_data = json.loads(jsonInput.read())


cols=['id','title','authorname','authortmain','writers','slotinfo']
mergeList = []
for i,books in enumerate(json_data["books"]):



    for j in range(len(books ["description"][0]['author'])):
        id=books['id']

        title=books["story"]['title']
        authorname=books["description"][0]['author'][j]['name']
        authortmain=books["description"][0]['author'][j]['main']
        writers=books["story"]['writers']
        slotinfo=books["story"]['slot']

        mergeList.append((id,title,authorname,authortmain,writers,slotinfo))
```

It gives me the below output: The writers and slot info comes as a list but I need to merge them using a spearator.

Output I got:

```
id,title,authorname,authortmain,writers,slotinfo
1,Lonely lion,John,1,"[{'lastName': 'John', 'firstName': 'Louis'}, {'lastName': 'Nick', 'firstName': 'Fed'}]","[{'slotid': 1112, 'region': {'US': 11, 'CA': 1}}]"
1,Lonely lion,Jeroge,0,"[{'lastName': 'John', 'firstName': 'Louis'}, {'lastName': 'Nick', 'firstName': 'Fed'}]","[{'slotid': 1112, 'region': {'US': 11, 'CA': 1}}]"
1,Lonely lion,Peter,0,"[{'lastName': 'John', 'firstName': 'Louis'}, {'lastName': 'Nick', 'firstName': 'Fed'}]","[{'slotid': 1112, 'region': {'US': 11, 'CA': 1}}]"
2,Lonely lion,Jeroge,1,"[{'lastName': 'John', 'firstName': 'Louis'}, {'lastName': 'Nick', 'firstName': 'Fed'}]","[{'slotid': 1112, 'region': {'US': 11, 'CA': 1}}]"
```

But I want to merge the writers info and for the slotinfo using "/" as a separator.
I need to run other loops but I am little confused how can I implement that.

desired output:

```
1,Lonely lion,John,1,"John,Louis/Nick,Fed","US: 11/CA: 1"
1,Lonely lion,Jeroge,0,"John,Louis/Nick,Fed","US: 11/CA: 1"
1,Lonely lion,Peter,0,"John,Louis/Nick,Fed","US: 11/CA: 1"
2,Lonely lion,Jeroge,1,"John,Louis/Nick,Fed","US: 11"
```

Comment: Unless you are specifically asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in `python3.x`. In `python2.7`, `encoding='UTF-8'`will not work.

```py
import json

with open(jsonFilename, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as jsonInput:
    json_data = json.loads(jsonInput.read())


cols=['id','title','authorname','authortmain','writers','slotinfo']
mergeList = []
for i,books in enumerate(json_data["books"]):



    for j in range(len(books ["description"][0]['author'])):
        id=books['id']

        title=books["story"]['title']
        authorname=books["description"][0]['author'][j]['name']
        authortmain=books["description"][0]['author'][j]['main']
        # writers=books["story"]['writers']
        writers = []
        for writer in books['story']['writers']:
            name = '{},{}'.format(writer['firstName'], writer['lastName'])
            writers.append(name)
        # slotinfo=books["story"]['slot']
        writers = '/'.join(writers)
        slotinfo = []
        for slot in books['story']['slot']:
            for key,value in slot['region'].items():
                item = '{}: {}'.format(key, value)
                slotinfo.append(item)
        slotinfo = '/'.join(slotinfo)

        mergeList.append((id,title,authorname,authortmain,writers,slotinfo))
        
print(mergeList)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I am wondering if writer['firstName'] is not available then it will through error